# Why doesnt my Code work? (Simple "Guess the Word"-Game in Python)

Tags: python

I'm learning Python for fun at the moment, and it went all well until now. I'm trying to extend the "Guess the Word"-Game, for example being able to let the Player choose a Word by himself (when 2 People play, 1 chooses the Word, the other guesses) I bet that my Mistake is obvious to me as soon as you point it out, but I'm gonna ask anyway. Well, here is the Code. I put in the entire Program, even tough only the top part should matter. I just put in the rest because it isn't much and maybe you guys can understand it better then.

```
print("Do you wish to set the Word yourself, or let the program choose?")
user_input = input("1 for own Input - 0 for Program-Input")
if user_input == 1:
    Keyword = input("Type in the Word you want to use!")
else:
    Keyword = "castle"
    word = list(Keyword)
    length = len(word)
    right = list ("_" * length)
    used_letters = list()
    finished = False
    while finished == False:
        guess = input("Guess a Letter!")
        if guess not in Keyword:
            print("This letter is not in the word. Sorry...")
        for letter in word:
            if letter == guess:
                index = word.index(guess)
                right[index] = guess
                word[index] = "_"
        if guess in used_letters[0:100]:
            print("You already used that letter before!")
        else:
            used_letters.append(guess)
            list.sort(used_letters)
        print(right)
        print("Used letters:")
        print(used_letters)
        if list(Keyword) == right:
            print("You win!")
            finished = True
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

My problem is, I wanna add the Function to be able to choose if you want to set a Word yourself, or use the word the Program has, defined as "Keyword". But no matter what I input, it always starts with "Guess a Letter" instead of skipping down to where the program sets the Keyword. Thank you in advance for your answers! :)

Comment: You should name your variable with [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) naming convention, `keyword` instead of `Keyword`

Comment: `input` returns a string, not an integer. So you should test `if user_input == "1":`

Comment: You can use [this](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html) to visualize your program and find bugs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the question asking guide before posting questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 issues with your code.

1. You put the entire block of code into the `else` statement. This means that if the `if user_input == 1:` block ever executed, you would only ask your user for a word and then the program would end because the `else` statement would be skipped.
2. You are using  `if user_input == 1:` as your check and this will never be true because user inputs are always read in as strings. A string 1 will never equal the integer 1. This is why your program always skips to the else statement. You need to do `if int(user_input) == 1:`

Comment: hank you didnt know that :)

Comment: You can just move the shared code outside of any indentation blocks...this way you use the if...else to choose the keyword and then the rest of the code will always execute.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you collect a user's input using the `input` function, it is a `string`, not `int`. this means you will have to either parse the value into an `int` or evaluate it with a string.

option 1: parsing to `int`:

```
user_input = int(input("1 for own Input - 0 for Program-Input"))
```

option 2: evaluating with `string`:

```
if user_input == "1":
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string not a integer so it can never be equal to 1 instead it will be equal to `"1"`. 
Plus the code for the user guessing only runs when the program chooses the word so it needs to be unindented.

As a side note your code currently registered capital letters as being different from lower case, you can fix this by putting a `.lower()` after each input which will turn all capital letters into lowercase.

```
print("Do you wish to set the Word yourself, or let the program choose?: ")
user_input = input("1 for own Input - 0 for Program-Input")
if user_input == "1":
    Keyword = input("Type in the Word you want to use: ").lower()
else:
    Keyword = "castle"
word = list(Keyword)
length = len(word)
right = list ("_" * length)
used_letters = list()
finished = False
while finished == False:
    guess = input("Guess a Letter: ").lower()
    if guess not in Keyword:
        print("This letter is not in the word. Sorry...")
    for letter in word:
        if letter == guess:
            index = word.index(guess)
            right[index] = guess
            word[index] = "_"
    if guess in used_letters[0:100]:
        print("You already used that letter before!")
    else:
        used_letters.append(guess)
        list.sort(used_letters)
    print(right)
    print("Used letters:")
    print(used_letters)
    if list(Keyword) == right:
        print("You win!")
        finished = True
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```